# Is there a verb meaning to accompany a superior person to help him/her through out his/her travel?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, verbs, nouns, british-english

I tried to find the verb for the action of a person traveling along with a superior person (in rank or age) to help throughout the journey. I couldn't find out one.
Example:

> Jack _____ his mom to her business trip, just to manage reservations and to ease her trip.

Common verbs include accompanying, escorting, travelling-along. But these words  do not really give the essence of help. Escort does, but it is not flexible enough.

The nouns include servant. Servant, in the present world sounds harsh on ears.

The example sentence could've been better, but I cannot think of one.
To keep it clear, my search is related to travel.
I hope answers from you. Thanks

Comment: I think that we would need to understand the social or formal context and possibly the time period you're referring to, context could help narrow it down considerably.

Comment: *Escort*, perhaps?

Comment: Jack **accompanied** his mom **on** her business trip, **mainly** to manage reservations and to **make her trip easier.** In broad terms, if A accompanies B, it is clear that B is the more important person

Comment: @Greybeard true, but not always. A friend can accompany another friend, no importance meant between them. And 'accompany' is a broader term and cannot be restricted or understood as help(for a superior)

Comment: @RawahaKB. I think you misunderstand. The *semantics* of "A accompanied B" is that B is the **theme** of the sentence (even if A and B are equals) and thus the focus (the more important) of the two. If it is a son and his mother, then the relationship is obvious. There is a verb *to attend* that used to serve your purpose but is now as archaic as the master/servant relationship that it implies. In Current AmE and BrE, **accompany** will convey your meaning idiomatically.

Comment: @Greybeard thanks for explanation. But still help is missing in the theme, though importance is clear. And your suggestion of 'to attend' is helpful for me.

Comment: @RawahaKB. I think you misunderstand. "Theme" is a technical term in semantics: OED: d. Linguistics. That part of a sentence which indicates what is being talked about. 
1959   J. Firbas in Brno Stud. in Eng. *Those sentence elements which convey something that is known, or may be inferred, from the verbal or from the situational context..are to be regarded as the communicative basis, as the theme of the sentence.*

Comment: A **bat man** gets used in the military.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Usually written ***batman***, after a *bat-saddle* (for supplies) of a cavalry officer.

Answer (score 1):

**Escort (noun):** An escort is a person who travels with someone in order to protect or guard them. - [*Collins Dictionary*](http://collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/escort)

**Example:** He arrived with a police escort shortly before half past nine.

**Escort (verb):** If you escort someone somewhere, you accompany them there, usually in order to make sure that they leave a place or get to their destination.

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

**Escort (noun):** a companion or guard for someone or something. - [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/escort?topic=taking-someone-somewhere-or-telling-them-the-way)

**Example:** Anytime a clerk transfers money, he is provided with an armed escort.

**Escord (verb):** to go with someone or something as a companion or guard.

**Example:** He escorted her to her car in the parking lot because it was after dark.

### ☆━━✥✥✥━━☆☆━━✥✥✥━━☆☆━━✥✥✥━━☆

**Usher (verb):** If you usher someone somewhere, you show them where they should go, often by going with them. - [*Collins Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/usher)

**Example:** I ushered him into the office. (Formal)

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

**Usher (verb):** to show someone where they should go, or to make someone go where you want them to go. - [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/usher)

**Example:** She ushered us into her office and offered us coffee.

### ☆━━✥✥✥━━☆☆━━✥✥✥━━☆☆━━✥✥✥━━☆

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 'Escort' is very close to my query. But I'm trying to find word with help. Protection is subset of help.

Comment: 'Help' them with what? You mean guide them where they should go?

Comment: Yes, that could be one. And all other travel related help one can think of (usually performed by servants at station)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps re-word it to use a noun not a verb.

Jack served as his mom's assistant for her business trip, just to manage reservations and to ease the trip.

Jack served as his mom's secretary for her business trip, just to manage reservations and to ease the trip.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the verb **chaperone** given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/chaperone) as

> **chaperone**
>   VERB
>
> Accompany and look after or supervise.
>   *He's climbed Everest ten times, in good weather and bad, from the north and from the south, by himself and chaperoning clients.*

So your sentence could be

> Jack **chaperoned** his mom on her business trip, to manage reservations and to make her journey easy.

---

In the noun form, Lexico gives

> **1** A person who accompanies and looks after another person or group of people.
>   *Without police chaperones, organizers were worried for participants' safety.*

Please note the older use of the term:

> **1.1** *dated* An older woman responsible for the decorous behaviour of a young unmarried girl at social occasions.

So my suggestion inverts the politics of the older meaning.

Comment: Thanks. I came across this word before my question. I dropped it from my query because it is something related to supervision/overseeing. supervision/overseeing, in my knowledge cannot be used for assistance of a superior person (esp. in rank), though they are related to assistance generally.

Comment: The example about climbing Everest supports my use. Even traditionally, the chaperone would not necessarily *control* their charge: just look out for them.

Comment: But most of the examples in Lexico.com are giving the essence, opposite to my search.

Comment: @RawahaKB and what is wrong with the intimation that you are looking after / taking charge of your mother, and making sure she doesn't get into any trouble, like nipping out for a boogie in the wrong neighbourhood?

Comment: @weather_wane I agree with you on that. Example sentences are next crucial thing after definitions. Most (not all) of the example sentences for chaperone give us the inverted relationship of rank. But still it could be used in many situations but not mine, this time

Comment: @RawahaKB perhaps that is because recorded examples are history.

Comment: Yes, history of the usage of word as well

Comment: What I mean, is if the usage politics have changed, then historic finds won't support it.

Answer (score 0):

**Aide**

*Aide* is an American short form of aide-de-camp, originally a military term for an assistant to a higher ranking officer, now more general.  The son is acting as an aide to his mother—-arranging travel, getting tickets, paying cab drivers, and the like.

As a verb, aided, assisted, helped, in addition to “acted as an aide.”

See the definition at https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/aide

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply say, "Jack helped his mom on her business trip. . . ."

But since you're asking for a word that relates to travel, *escorted* is a strong choice, because it does mean more than mere companionship. It implies a degree of cordial service or assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Jack _____ his mom to her business trip, just to manage reservations and to ease her trip.

These following two words may describe what you are wanting though I have not encountered the first two frequently if at all in my readings. Native speakers be the judges.

From Merriam-Webster

**Convoy**: to go along with in order to provide assistance, protection, or companionship

**Tote**: to support and take from one place to another

**Squire**: to go along with in order to provide assistance, protection, or companionship

I will go with **squire**. And also I am only assuming **convoy** and **convey** may have had similar origins.

Other words may be

- superintendent
- supervise
- oversee